# Is there an parameter in spark XGBoostClassifier package like 'subsample_weight' in Python XGBoost fit() function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, xgboost

In my current XGBoostClassify task, `I try to set different weights for different samples`. The package I use is XGBoostClassifier in spark.

I know in Python XGBoost function fit(), there is an parameter called **subsample_weight**, which allows you to assign different weights for different samples/instances. But I failed to find similar parameters in spark XGBoost package.

Here is the fit() function in XGBoost package of Python.

```
fit(X, y, sample_weight=None, eval_set=None, eval_metric=None, early_stopping_rounds=None, verbose=True, xgb_model=None, sample_weight_eval_set=None, callbacks=None)
```

So, **How can I set weight for each sample in XGBoost of spark?** Any solutions or ideas will be appreciated!